# How do I add a mergebot to my Plastic SCM project

Tags: automation, version-control, devops, git-merge, plasticscm

In Plastic SCM documentation, I saw mentions of mergebot and other automation tools and I'd like to also add them to my project.

But I know nothing about DevOps stuff and I'm wondering how to do it. I found info that I need to use `webadmin` for this but I struggle to set up it.

Could anyone please provide some instruction steps or link to documentation? From what I tried to search there is different info about this and it's spread among a bunch of web pages (and none of them helped me).

And BTW, are automation tools available at all in CLoud Edition? And does it matter whether I work centralized or decentralized? (I use the former option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I contacted Plastic SCM support and it turns out mergebot isn't available in Cloud Edition, only in Enterprise